# Profile Update Notifications

Tags: solspace-user

We're using User to manage member profiles for a training academy. Members update their profiles in templates utilizing the user:edit tag.

The client would like to receive notifications whenever a member updates their profile.

I see Profile Update Admin Notification Template in the User settings, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to work. I've added an email address in the field above it, and I've placed this code in the field, but am not receiving any notifications (I've confirmed that other email notifications are being sent):

```
Date updated: {update_date}
{changed}
   {award_name} // I also tried {name} per the instructions
   {value}
{/changed}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with User and will be corrected in the next release (User 4.0.11). In the meantime, anyone affected by this issue can [contact Solspace Support](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/create-ticket/user) for a patched copy. :)